# Best option to disabled input type formControlName matInput? Angular Material

Tags: php

I need best option to disabled input matInput type filed in Angular Material?
Check my code:

```
<div></mat-label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the formControl in your controller.
Say I have a `Form Group` called `myForm` which contains a control called `name`.
You can set the `disabled` to `true` when initializing the form.

```
const myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   name: [{value:'',disabled: true}]
})
```

Or you can dynamically disable control using:

```
myForm.get('name').disable();
```